# Getting error while installing keras and tensorflow on jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

```
runcell(0, 'D:/python/ann.py')
```

Using TensorFlow backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in 
from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *

File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in 
_pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()

File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
_mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)

File "C:\Users\lenovo\anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)

File "C:\Users\lenovo\anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
return _load(spec)

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "D:\python\ann.py", line 1, in 
import keras

File "C:\Users\lenovo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras_*init*_.py", line 3, in 
from . import utils

File "C:\Users\lenovo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils_*init*_.py", line 6, in 
from . import conv_utils

File "C:\Users\lenovo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\conv_utils.py", line 9, in 
from .. import backend as K

File "C:\Users\lenovo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend_*init*_.py", line 84, in 
from .tensorflow_backend import *

File "C:\Users\lenovo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 5, in 
import tensorflow as tf

File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_*init*_.py", line 41, in 
from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util

File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python_*init*_.py", line 50, in 
from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow

File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 69, in 
raise ImportError(msg)

Comment: pip install tensorflow , pip install keras ,, both i have done still facing issue

Comment: If possible install tensorflow 2.2, keras is not included directly in tensorflow and ensures compatibility

Comment: no,its not working